# Selecting bones by name without clicking

Tags: armature, bones, selection-tools

Selecting bones can be pretty tedious, especially when you are switching back and forth between armatures. I wish that when I switch to pose mode, there was a way to typeahead search for a bone by name, hit enter and the bone is selected. Is there any way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pose mode, 3d viewport menu, you can find select->select pattern.  This lets you select all bones by name.  It's intended for use with a wildcard operator, for selecting all bones with a particular naming system (like *.L), but you can use it for selecting single bones.  You can assign a hotkey to this menu item by right clicking on the menu item and selecting "Assign shortcut".

Comment: This is awesome assigned to "Quick Favorites". Only slightly devastating that it doesn't auto-focus the input field when it opens, but certainly better than trying to hand select specifics! Thank you!