# Filter objects by name without their parents

Tags: objects, interface, outliner, object-mode, select

When I type object names in the "search bar" in Outliner, it shows not only the matched objects but their whole hierarchy:

[image]

I don't want to know what's their parents and parents' parents. I want the objects whose names matched the search string. Is it possible? If not, is there another way (or addon) to select objects by name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting bones by name without clicking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227333/selecting-bones-by-name-without-clicking)

Comment: @batFINGER No because I asked for a general way to filter objects by name, not bones.

Comment: While clearing the "Show Children" in the Outliner filter works for non-Armature Objects, it doesn't clear up "the mess" with Armatures.  I voted thumbs up on your question, because I often get frustrated by the deeply indented and widely separated.  "Show Children" IMHO is therefore inconsistent.  I may visit devtalk to suggest something is needed.

Comment: @batFINGER I just tried the Pattern search in your provided link.  Didn't work for me in 2.93.4 with Armature in Object or Edit mode.  yikes.